# Button color not changing in android studio with <Button> tag

Tags: android, xml

i want to change my button color but it won't change.
this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

so in this layout, i have a button and for customization, i create a Drawable resource file called "button_background" and in it i wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

so the stroke and corner tags are functioning correctly, but the solid tag related to color isn't working. and the button background stays purple.

i try <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton> but i want to figure out why  isn't working.